# Calculate percentage for each row for all values associated with the same customer in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains customer data as such

```
ID  Name  Product  Quantity
1  Rick  Pen  10
1  Rick  Eraser  13
1  Rick  Ink  23
2  Marge  PostIt  13
2  Marge  Glue  7
3  Frank  Pen  13
3  Frank  Glue  6
3  Frank  Ink  8
```

I want to get an output where for each customer, I get a percentage for what the quantity for each row would be based on the total quantity for that particular customer. For instance, Customer 1 has 3 items for which the quantity would total to 46. So the first row would be (10/46)*100, which comes down to roughly 21.74 percent. This is how the Output should look like.

```
ID  Name  Product  Quantity  Total
1  Rick  Pen  10  21.74
1  Rick  Eraser  13  28.26
1  Rick  Ink  23  50.00
2  Marge  PostIt  13  65.00
2  Marge  Glue  7  35.00
3  Frank  Pen  13  48.15
3  Frank  Glue  6  22.22
3  Frank  Ink  8  29.63
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sum with partition by as below

```
Select *, PercentSum = Format((Quantity*1.0)/(sum(Quantity) over(partition by Id)), 'p') 
   from yourtable
```

Output as below:

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+------------+
| Id | Name  | Product | Quantity | PercentSum |
+----+-------+---------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Rick  | Pen     |       10 | 21.74 %    |
|  1 | Rick  | Eraser  |       13 | 28.26 %    |
|  1 | Rick  | Ink     |       23 | 50.00 %    |
|  2 | Marge | PostIt  |       13 | 65.00 %    |
|  2 | Marge | Glue    |        7 | 35.00 %    |
|  3 | Frank | Pen     |       13 | 48.15 %    |
|  3 | Frank | Glue    |        6 | 22.22 %    |
|  3 | Frank | Ink     |        8 | 29.63 %    |
+----+-------+---------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Kannan. This was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Gives your expected Result

```
;With cte(ID, Name, Product, Quantity)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'Rick' ,'Pen' , 10    UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Rick' ,'Eraser'  ,13 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Rick' ,'Ink' , 23    UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Marge','PostIt' , 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Marge','Glue' , 7    UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Frank','Pen'  ,13    UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Frank','Glue' , 6    UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Frank','Ink' , 8
)
SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,Product
    ,Quantity
    ,CAST(ROUND(Quantity * 1. / (
                SUM(Quantity) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID
                    )
                ) * 100, 3) AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS [Total%]
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1,5
```

Result

```
ID  Name    Product Quantity    Total%
-----------------------------------------
1   Rick    Pen     10          21.74
1   Rick    Eraser  13          28.26
1   Rick    Ink     23          50.00
2   Marge   Glue    7           35.00
2   Marge   PostIt  13          65.00
3   Frank   Glue    6           22.22
3   Frank   Ink     8           29.63
3   Frank   Pen     13          48.15
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Srini131. I tried running the query but I'm getting an Error: "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.". I tried Kannan's solution and that worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on 2008 or older which doesn't support partition by in the sum function you can do something like this. If you are on 2012 or later I would use the answer from Kannan.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , Name varchar(10)
    , Product varchar(10)
    , Quantity int
)

insert @Something
(
    ID
    , Name
    , Product
    , Quantity
)
Values
(1, 'Rick', 'Pen', 10)
, (1, 'Rick', 'Eraser', 13)
, (1, 'Rick', 'Ink', 23)
, (2, 'Marge', 'PostIt', 13)
, (2, 'Marge', 'Glue', 7)
, (3, 'Frank', 'Pen', 13)
, (3, 'Frank', 'Glue', 6)
, (3, 'Frank', 'Ink', 8)

select s.ID
    , s.Name
    , s.Product
    , s.Quantity
    , TotalPercentage = convert(numeric(5,2), (s.Quantity * 1.0 / total.TotalPurchased) * 100)
from @Something s
cross apply
(
    select sum(s2.Quantity) as TotalPurchased
        , ID
    from @Something s2
    where s2.ID = s.ID
    group by s2.ID
) total
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean. This works great. Thank you for your help.